# Convert ActorSelection to ActorRef

Tags: scala, akka, cluster-computing, actor

I have some distribuited actors and I need the ActorRef for these actors. So I tried this line (it is in the MemberUp code).

```
implicit val resolveTimeout = Timeout(5 seconds)
var act=Await.result(context.system.actorSelection(RootActorPath(member.address)/"user"/"myactor2").resolveOne(), resolveTimeout.duration)
```

But I always get the following exception:

> [ERROR] [11/03/2015 16:01:58.530]
>   [ClusterSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5]
>   [akka://ClusterSystem/user/myactor1] Actor not found for:
>   ActorSelection[Anchor(akka://ClusterSystem/), Path(/user/myactor2)]
>   akka.actor.ActorNotFound: Actor not found for:
>   ActorSelection[Anchor(akka://ClusterSystem/), Path(/user/myactor2)]

I tried increasing the timeout to 15 or 20 seconds, but I still get the same error. The problem is that if I keep the ActorSelection (

`act=context.system.actorSelection(RootActorPath(member.address)/"user"/"myactor2");`

), the line works fine and I can send messages to the other actor. Why?

Answer (score 0):

why not just simply

```
val actor = context.system.actorSelection(RootActorPath(member.address)/"user"/"myactor2")
actor ! message // you can directly send message to it!
```

If you are sure there is an actor exist in that path, it is okey to send message like that. As the official doc said:

> `actorSelection` only ever looks up existing actors when messages are delivered, i.e. does not create actors, or verify existence of actors when the selection is created.